# audio version of Analects

Tags: classical-chinese, spoken, audio

I'm currently learning classical Chinese, and was wondering if somewhere online there were spoken versions of works like the Analects (obviously in Chinese.) A version where it is easy to find the audio for specific passages would be fantastic.

Comment: There are many on Youtube. Go there, search analects, pick one you like, and download it. There are freewares that convert mp4 to audio file of various formats if you only want audio.

Comment: @joehua On youtube, I've only found either very low quality audio recording, or incomplete recordings.

Comment: What about this one: https://youtu.be/bBGdLpZODDY  ?

Comment: @joehua The recording is good (so thank you), but the numbering system is totally different from the kind of standard numbering system found in https://ctext.org/analects for example. That makes it  extremely cumbersome  to look up specific passages.

Comment: Are you looking for audio or video recording? How would you "look up" specific passages in an audio recording?

Answer (score 2):

go https://www.ximalaya.com/
search any classical chinese audio version you want.Remember to use chinese and add 原文 after its name.
Books suggested:

论语（Analects），孟子，大学，中庸， this four are about Thought

资治通鉴，史记，this two about History,they are huge

古文观止,little hard

Answer (score 1):

I think this should suit you.

弘化社数字图书馆-馆藏图书-论语
http://book.honghuashe.com/library/detail/92387

Comment: Each chapter of this audio series has its own audio.

Comment: also here:  https://cup.columbia.edu/supplemental-materials-for-how-to-read-chinese-prose